# Angular access variable outside $http success function

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-promise, angular-http

I am trying to loop through some json values outside the actual function. could anyone help me?

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $http){

$scope.contents = [];

$http.get('/data4estate/data_model.php')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.contents = data;
    });

for (i = 0; i < $scope.contents.length; i++) {
    console.log( $scope.contents[i].name);
}
```

});

Comment: `$http` is asynchronous, the for loop is running before `$scope.contents` has been populated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Do not understand what you mean

Comment: Read the documentation for angulars http module, this is something you should understand before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.contents = [];

      $http.get('/data4estate/data_model.php')
          .success(function (data) {
              $scope.contents = data;
          });

      $scope.$watch('contents', function () {
          for (i = 0; i < $scope.contents.length; i++) {
              console.log($scope.contents[i].name);
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('/data4estate/data_model.php').then(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(dataItem) {
        console.log(dataItem);

    });
    /*once you assign the result to $scope here, all the bindings
      in your view will update automatically */
    $scope.contents = response.data;
});
```